# Arnold's proof for the insolvability of the quintic

Tags: galois-theory, quintics

I am trying to understand Arnold's proof for the insolvability of the quintic from the manuscript:

https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/394/ArnoldQuintic.pdf

which is actually well written. However, I am stumbling in Page 4 where the author says "By contrast, Exercise 1 implies that any combination of the four field operations, continuous functions, and a *single nesting* of radicals would produce a loop." and the subsequent Proposition 6.

Where does the single nesting of radicals come in Exercise 1? There is no nesting of radicals mentioned before this statement. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to suggest the following book : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/abel.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjL8N_Lib_kAhWUeisKHZaJAwYQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0IHWaQ07tfCvLbTznsTOY6

Comment: Thank you very much for this insightful book. I need to read it.

Answer (score 1):

In Exercise 1, take $\alpha = 1/3$, say. That's a cube root, ie a single nested radical.